# Recolor background dynamically

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to create a language choice in XAML, but the designer has created this mockup:

[image]

Now I have to follow this design, but I don't know if it is possible to create such a dynamic background in XAML using the `Border` tag?

Do I need to extract this as an image, and set it as the background for all the rows? Or can I make the background behind the flag darker in a certain way (ex: only round the left corners)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to only round certain corners of your border, by using `<Border CornerRadius="10,0,0,10">`

Comment: Stupid me, but I'm still going to leave it here for people in the future ;)